# Proper sharing audio device in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, audio-recording

Our application has multi-access audio device (mic) in order to record and show audio levels on the screen. It was working fine in all Windows environments except Windows 8/64bit (haven't tried it on 32bit system) where it fails to record from the source. I tried to disable 'Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device' feature of the recording device/mic but it didn't help at all.

Are there any other settings I can change in Windows 8 in order to properly share the device between the applications?